# The right place for running a jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Adding different plugins, scripts and other jquery the code gets pretty messy.
What is the right place for running each jquery, and does it need separated functions for each element.

Some of the scripts are runs like this in the head of the page:

`$(function(){ ...`

`jQuery(function() { ...`

and other need to be at the end:

`$( ".add" ).button({ ...`

is it wrong to merge all of the functions into one `$(function(){ ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is NO hard-n-fast rule for where to put a `jQuery` snippet.

You put it at correct place where it is needed.

- `$(function(){` is short for `$(document).ready(function() {`. It is an event, which executes when the document is ready for processing.
- `$( ".add" ).button({` is assigning a plugin(probably) to an selector. Every plugins have their own event triggers and they will occur either automatically or manually like through, `hovers` and `clicks`

You should put(always) code at the correct event triggers/function call for them to function properly.

## But

If you are using too many scripts on your page, that it is slowing the load time. Then they are better when they are placed right before the `</body>`

---

#### References

Read jQuery Events Documentation <sup>*[[docs here]](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)*</sup> very clearly to understand, where to put your code effectively

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an alias for `jQuery`, so you can pick what ever you prefer and stick to it. There are some advantages of using `$`. It is slightly more compact and commonly used in the jQuery documentation.

In your examples your anonymous function was called when document was ready. One thing that is good to know is that images might not be loaded when using document ready. You can be sure that are DOM elements are there, so your jQuery selectors should work correctly.

If you have multiple `$(document).ready(function () { /* your code here */ });` lines then all them are executed, so they don't override each other. For example if you multiple JS files. You should separate your JS files for maintainability.